# What are the different java class icons in netbeans 8.1?

Tags: netbeans

See the image below, what do the different icons represent ?

For info :

- HardwareApi is a @Stateless session bean.
- Substation is an @Entity
- ContactType is an enum
- Switchgear is an @Entity
- SwitchgearContact is an @Entity

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It appears the clear white icons such as `Switchgear` and `SwitchgearContact` are different icons because they are abstract classes.

Enums have a red dot in addition to the icon for regular classes.